# What is the right way to create a constant pool for inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, inline-assembly

The problem is that inside a C function I have an inline assembly.
Something like

```
  ldr r7, =0xdeadbeef
  svc 0
```

If a literal pool wasn't created explicitly (this is the case), assembler
creates one at the end of the translation unit. Usually this is fine, but if the
translation unit turns out to be really huge, this doesn't work, because the
literal pool is too far from the ldr instruction.

So, I wonder what is the best way to handle the problem. The most obvious way is
to create a literal pool manually inside the inline assembly:

```
  ldr r7, =0xdeadbeef
  svc 0
  b 1f
  .ltorg
1:
```

Or

```
  ldr r7, 1f
  svc 0
  b 2f
1:
  .word 0xdeadbeef
2:
```

Unfortunately, this leads to a suboptimal code because of the redundant branch
instruction. I don't expect assembler to be clever enough to find an appropriate
place for the constant pool inside the function. What I would like to do is to
create a constant pool at the end of the function. Is there any way to tell the
compiler (gcc) to create a literal pool *at the end* of the function?

**PS** I ended up using `movw/movt` pair instead of constant pools. Though,
firstly, the movw/movt solution is slightly less portable than literal pools and,
secondly, I simply wonder if it is possible to use constant pools in inline assembly
both reliably and efficiently.

---

***Update:*** *So, what is the best way to handle the problem?*

To force the toolchain to create a constant pool after the function one can put
the function in a separate code section. It works because at the end of a translation unit assembler generates
separate constant pools for each section.

Though, in fact, the *best* way is to avoid loading constants into registers in
inline assembly at all. It's better to let the compiler do that. In my case I
eventually wrote a code similar to

```
register int var asm("r7") = 0xdeadbeef;
asm volatile("svc 0\n" :: "r" (var));
```

Comment: Probably right way is to use constraints but that's like magic. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-ffunction-sections` and as per [query on `-ffunction-section`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274804/query-on-ffunction-section-fdata-sections-options-of-gcc), use a `ld --gc-sections` to remove unused code.

There is the obvious of splitting up the file.

A solution that should work is to use a `naked` function with an `unused` annotation as it is never called.  Place a single `.ltorg` here and also put both functions in a special section; `.text.ltorg_kludge` for instance.  The linker script should use `.text*` and functions in identical sub-sections are placed together.  In some ways this is like splitting up the file as the compiler will try to inline `static` functions.

You may rely on the compiler emitting functions as encountered in the source without a special section.  However, I am not sure if this is a standard or happen-stance.  Compilers may optimize better by emitting function in some DAG ordering of the call hierarchy.

---

Aside: `movw`/`movt` is more efficient due to cache effects.  It is also works with ARMv6 and above Thumb2 code.  I don't see portability as a big deal (as inline assembler is non-portable and you probably prefer performance over *portability*), but the question is relevant to ARMv4/5 users.

---

I investigated the use of the **R** constraint from [gcc machine constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html),

> R 
>         An item in the constant pool

However, a [sample with gcc-4.8](http://goo.gl/rCjAib) gives an error *impossible constraint*.  Using alternative letters like **C** also give the same error message.  Inspection of the [source contraints.md](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/constraints.md;hb=HEAD) seems to indicate that the **R** constraint is a documentation only feature.  Unfortunate, as it sounds purpose built to solve this issue.

It is possible to have the compiler load the value, but this maybe sub-optimal depending on the `inline` assembler.  For example,

```
  asm(" add %0, %0, %1\n" : "+r" (0xdeadbeef) : "r" (0xbaddeed0));
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I like your idea of fiddling with sections! As
for "R" constraint, currently the comment in constraints.md says "We used to
have constraint letters for S and R in ARM state, but all uses of these now
appear to have been removed".

Comment: It's also relavent to armv6 systems, armv6t2 has movw/movt, bit baseline armv6 does not.