# gcc compile function in ifdef

Tags: c, gcc

I have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test2()
{
    printf("start test2\n");

    printf("end test2\n");
}

void main ()
{

    printf("abc\n");
    #ifdef A
        test2();
    #endif

}
```

compile it with `gcc test.c -o test -static -D B`

when I run the program I see that `test2` didn't run (that good)

But when I run strings I can see that `end test2` in binary file. why? gcc didn't need to compile it !

When I compile this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test1();
void test2()
{
    printf("start test2\n");
    test1();
    printf("end test2\n");
}

void main ()
{

    printf("abc\n");
    #ifdef A
        test2();
    #endif

}
```

with `gcc test.c -o test -static -D B`

Gcc tell me that `undefined reference to 'test1'` why? I didn't want that gcc even compile function `test2` so gcc didn't need to know that I used that undefined function.

What can I do that gcc will not look on `test2` when I pass `-D` that not equal to `A` ?

Comment: Wrap `test2` with `#ifdef A` also.  Also, maybe turn up optimization.

Comment: duplicate of [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld) and [discard unused functions in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033595/discard-unused-functions-in-gcc) and other things that can be found by searching

Comment: It was only the call that was compiled conditionally, not the function itself (although it could be optimised out).

Answer (score 3):

The function `test2` can still be called from a function in an external module, even if you don't call it here, so the definition of the function must exist.

If you change the function to `static` so that it can only be referenced from the current file and increase the optimization to `-O1` or higher, the entire function is optimized out.

Comment: `static` make this function available only of this file , but I want to call `test2` from another file , so I looking of another solution

Answer (score 1):

By default linker does not remove the dead code.

use : `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fdce- -Wl,--gc-sections -static` command line option

Comment: `-Wl`   ____________________

Comment: thank you ! that work ~ can please explain  more about this solution ? `fdata-sections` and `ffuntion-sections` separate each function to another sections , and `-Wl,--gc-sections` just remove the unused sections? why now the linker didn't search about `test1` ?  ,  by the way the string `end test2` still contain in final binary

Comment: It removes the "dead code" and data from the output file.\

Comment: The only problem is that in GMU site I see `When you specify these options, the assembler and linker create larger object and executable files and are also slower`. Is there any solution that not slow down the code and makes the solution file bigger??

Comment: It may increase the size of the static libraries, but not executables. At least on the platforms I use. I have no clue why they wtite something about execution time as it wqill be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a bit like saying "If I don't look at the tree, the tree is not there anymore." which is of course not true.

If you don't want to include a function in your program, remove it. (And all references to it)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test1();

#ifdef A
void test2()
{
    printf("start test2\n");
    test1();
    printf("end test2\n");
}
#endif

int main (void)
{
    printf("abc\n");
    #ifdef A
        test2();
    #endif
}
```