Remove unused data from bss restored section (c)
I've noticed that when using -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections and -Wl,--gc-sections, unused restored BSS sections are still mapped into memory, even though I expect them to be stripped. Why are they not removed? Is there a specific flag or an external GCC/Clang plugin that can remove them?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274804/query-on-ffunction-section-fdata-sections-options-of-gcc

What CPU? Can you provide an example of the source code and e.g. the map file?

@pmacfarlane cortex m4/m7
